# Set mouse callback updating source Image

Tags: opencv, mouseevent

I have the following code:

```
def click(action, x,y,flags,params):
    global a, image

    a = 40
    if action == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        patch = selectPatch(x,y)
        image = clone(x,y,patch,dummy)
        cv2.imshow('Image',image)


image = cv2.imread(r'...\blemish.png')
dummy = image.copy()
img = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

cv2.namedWindow('Image') 
cv2.setMouseCallback('Image',click)
  
k= 0
while k != 27:
    cv2.imshow('Image', image)    
    
    k = cv2.waitKey(20)


cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I am trying to basically make spot removal from scratch in opencv. Now this code works partially  when i click on the spot it clones the best fit from neighbourhood. However when i click the second time it undoes the first fix and applies fix to the second spot only. So it basically only fixes one spot and undoes any previous ones. So in essence what i think the problem is how to store the result as the original image and then updating it each time i make a click. I am not sure how to achieve this.

Comment: well, in the callback function you are assigning and overwriting `patch` and `image`. Maybe you instead want to add it so some list or something??

Comment: @Micka So you mean storing all the changes i make on the image(spot removals) to store those in a list and then apply them in the end?  My intention was to apply fixes on the spot so to click on image and imidiately fix the image and then continue applying fixes.

Comment: whatever you want to do, just persist it during/after the callback. Currently `image` is always cloned from the dummy